# Interwoven Teamsite

Tags: html, css, xml, teamsite

Anyone had any experience with Teamsite, I could use some advice...

Comment: You'll probably get better answers if you ask your specific question.

Comment: Do you still need advice?
Jan

Comment: I am currently working on TeamSite / LiveSite / OpenDeploy solutions with several customers (and with different versions)

I'll be glad to help you.
I know well the advantages / disadvantages of these solutions.

Regards,

Answer (score 8):

I loath Teamsite, I've had to use it for the last year (2010) at my <s>current</s> previous job, and it causes me and anyone I've met who uses it, an abnormal amount of frustration.

I'd stay away from it.

[a subjective answer to a vague question]

Comment: Completely agree. Under the hood it is unnecessarily complex. It has also not updated its core part as new technologies and practices have emerged in the market.

Answer (score 5):

Yes

Comment: Me, too. My advice: run the other way. :-)

Comment: +1 for accurately answering the question. And @ajm is correct - run. Run as fast as you can. Teamsite is an appalling mess.

Answer (score 1):

Disagree - TeamSite is a great tool when implemented well for the right reason.

Comment: Notice how the only positive answer about it comes from someone with exaclty **1 rep** (at the time of writing this - which is a year after they joined) ie they just signed up to stack overflow to disagree and then never used it again... hahaha. **Useful, i think not**

Comment: Teamsite is a good tool if you know how to use it and if you can benefit from leveraging its flexibility. I like it a lot - now that I know it well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the forums on Interwoven devnet? They used to be pretty good.

http://devnet.interwoven.com/site.fcgi